# Submit type with image

Tags: html

I am wanting to use input type submit rather than input type image but I want the submit type to use an image. Can this be done?

Comment: yeah, just change the background image of input[type=submit]

Answer (score 2):

You can attempt to style the `<input type='submit'>` with a CSS `background` statement:

```
input[type="submit"] {
  background-image: url("submit-img.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 0;
}
```